# How can i make select all statement in sqlite according to condition?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

What i have is sqlite helper class , and i have two tables like this :

```
public class InfoServicesNew extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    //master
    private String KEY_ID = "ID";
    private String KEY_CUSTOMER_ID = "CUSTOMERID";
    private String KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME = "CUSTOMER";
    private String KEY_DATE = "DATE";

    //details
    private String KEY_ID_DETAILS = "DETAILSID";
    private String KEY_ITEM_ID = "ITEMID";
    private String KEY_ITEM_QUANTITY = "ITEM";
    private String KEY_EXTRA = "EXTRA";



    private static String DB_NAME = "ALIBABA";
    public static String DB_TABLE_NAME = "MASTER";
    public static String DB_TABLE_NAME2 = "DETAIL";
    private static int DB_VERSION = 3;

    private static SQLiteDatabase database;
    public InfoServicesNew(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        database = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE_NAME + " (" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + KEY_CUSTOMER_ID +" TEXT,"  +
                KEY_CUSTOMER_NAME+" TEXT ,"+ KEY_DATE +" TEXT );");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE_NAME2 + " (" + KEY_ID_DETAILS
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + KEY_CUSTOMER_ID +" TEXT,"  +
                 KEY_ITEM_ID + " TEXT ," + KEY_ITEM_QUANTITY + " TEXT ,"+ KEY_EXTRA +" TEXT);");
    }
```

And i have made them correctly and i inserted data into them , but the thing is i want to make a select function which will be like this :

**select * from DETAIL where MASTER.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID==DETAIL.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID;**

Here is my select all function , how can i edit it so i can retrieve all the rows with the same customer id value in the other table?

Here is my propose select function :

```
public ArrayList<cartItems> selectAllDetails(String Db_name) {
        String columns[] = new String[] { KEY_ID_DETAILS, KEY_CUSTOMER_ID,KEY_ITEM_ID,KEY_ITEM_QUANTITY,KEY_EXTRA};
        Cursor c = database.query(Db_name, columns, null, null,null,null,null);

        int idIndex = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID_DETAILS);
        int customerId = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CUSTOMER_ID);
        int itemId = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEM_ID);
        int ItemQuantity = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEM_QUANTITY);
        int extra = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXTRA);
        ArrayList<cartItems> list = new ArrayList<cartItems>();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                list.add(new cartItems(c.getInt(idIndex), c.getString(customerId), c.getString(itemId), c.getString(ItemQuantity),c.getString(extra)));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return list;

    }
```

Please can anyone gave me a simple solution because i am new at sqlite?? thanks

Comment: try this **Select * from DETAIL inner join MASTER on DETAIL.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID = MASTER.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID**

Comment: ok where shall i put these sentence in my code? can you explain even more?

Comment: @s try as per my answer and let me know.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    String sql="Select * from DETAIL inner join MASTER on DETAIL.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID = MASTER.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID";

     Cursor c=database.rawQuery(sql, null);

    int idIndex = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID_DETAILS);
    int customerId = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CUSTOMER_ID);
    int itemId = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEM_ID);
    int ItemQuantity = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEM_QUANTITY);
    int extra = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXTRA);
    ArrayList<cartItems> list = new ArrayList<cartItems>();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            list.add(new cartItems(c.getInt(idIndex), c.getString(customerId), c.getString(itemId), c.getString(ItemQuantity),c.getString(extra)));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return list;
```

Comment: it gave me the following error on run : android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: DETAIL.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from DETAIL inner join MASTER on DETAIL.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID = MASTER.KEY_CUSTOMER_ID

Comment: @M D and i have checked that i have defined all of the columns clearly .. what is the problem?

Comment: just give your `Field Name` try this `String sql="Select * from DETAIL inner join MASTER on DETAIL.CUSTOMERID= MASTER.CUSTOMERID"`;